# AMQP secure connection / encrypted URI

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I want to establish an AMQP connection from my Java client to a RabbitMQ AMQP message broker. It actually works fine as described at https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html.

Im doing:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.setUsername(userName);
factory.setPassword(password);
factory.setVirtualHost(virtualHost);
factory.setHost(hostName);
factory.setPort(portNumber);
Connection conn = factory.newConnection();
```

or as an equivalent the following does the same:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.setUri("amqp://userName:password@hostName:portNumber/virtualHost");
Connection conn = factory.newConnection();
```

But am I right in the assumption that my username and password in the URI string are transmitted over the internet in plain? If this is the case, I would like to know how to get this authentication a little more secure.

Comment: have you seen https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html ?

Comment: I didn't, thanks. Will this basically be the same as SSL encrypted HTTP, just for AMQP?
And am I even right in thinking that my username and password will be transmitted in plain when connecting?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? If so, can you please post your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

By default amqp uses no encryption. So yes, as far as I read the documentation your username would indeed be sent as plain text within the amqp protocol.

RabbitMQ supports tls encryption of amqp as documented in the [official rabbitmq documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html).

So, in order to secure your connection you have to enable ssl auth in Rabbitmq and tell it where to find valid certificates.

For example in [`rabbitmq.conf`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#config-file):

```
listeners.ssl.default = 5671

ssl_options.cacertfile = /path/to/ca_certificate.pem
ssl_options.certfile   = /path/to/server_certificate.pem
ssl_options.keyfile    = /path/to/server_key.pem
ssl_options.verify     = verify_peer
ssl_options.fail_if_no_peer_cert = false
```